# How to get Genymotion VM to respect NAT settings and see host named sites?

Tags: android, virtualbox, nat, genymotion, hosts

I want to access a named virtual host on my Mac from the browser in Android running on Genymotion. Genymotion is a wrapper on VirtualBox, so it stands to reason that the same flags and features that are available to VirtualBox should be available to Genymotion virtual machines.

Initially (using an Ubuntu VM to test) I got that to work on an NAT network connection, with the caveat that I had to alias an IP other than 127.0.0.1 to my local network (because I figure that otherwise, the hostname will resolve to 127.0.0.1 on the virtual machine, where the site isn't).

`sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 192.168.0.100 up`

And with using the following, which get the host to resolve the addresses for the VM (and so use the host's hosts file):

    `VBoxManage modifyvm "Nexus 5 - Android 5" --natdnsproxy1 on
    VBoxManage modifyvm "Nexus 5 - Android 5" --natdnshostresolver1 on`

That worked for the Ubuntu VM, but not for the Genymotion VM. Next, I tried this:

`VBoxManage setextradata "Nexus 5 - Android 5" "VBoxInternal/Devices/virtio-net/1/LUN#0/Config/HostResolverMappings/ local-sites/HostIP" 192.168.0.100
VBoxManage setextradata "Nexus 5 - Android 5" "VBoxInternal/Devices/virtio-net/1/LUN#0/Config/HostResolverMappings/ local-sites/HostNamePattern" "*.local"`

Still no joy. It just doesn't resolve the DNS. I've edited the .vbox file by hand to be sure (I'm not sure that changing settings by command line seems to have an effect on Genymotion VMs), but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, d'oh. It does work and works well, and here's the reason that it didn't for me. I scrolled down the file to find the relevant section, but in fact I was editing the snapshot settings, not the settings for the current device.

Inside the node `<Hardware version="n">` where `n` is the version number, find `Adapter slot="1"` and modify the `NAT` section to look like this:

          `<NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="true" use-host-resolver="true"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>`

Further down, you could add rules in the `<GuestProperties>` sections, something like (for example):

      `<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/virtio-net/1/LUN#0/Config/HostResolverMappings/ local-sites/HostIP" value="192.168.0.100"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/virtio-net/1/LUN#0/Config/HostResolverMappings/ local-sites/HostNamePattern" value="*.local"/>`

I didn't need the rules once I got the host NAT part working, but that might be useful in other situations.

Anyway, I've seen a few questions about NAT from VirtualBox (or Genymotion) to the host's NAT resolution, so hopefully this helps someone. After all that it was actually very easy to get working. There are probably some other permutations and if anyone has additional pointers that would help someone, please add.